# Fraction inequality

Tags: inequality, fractions

Suppose we know that 
\begin{align}
\frac{a+b+d}{a'+b'+d'}\le M\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \frac{a+c+d}{a'+c'+d'}\le M
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{a'}\le \frac{b}{b'}\le\frac{d}{d'}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \frac{a}{a'}\le \frac{c}{c'}\le\frac{d}{d'}
\end{align}
and also that $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d'\in(0,1]$.

Is the following true?
\begin{align}
\frac{a+b+c+d}{a'+b'+c'+d'}\le M
\end{align}

Comment: why don't you search not for a counter example?

Comment: Why did you put the condition $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d'\in(0,1]$? The problem would be exactly the same (but slightly more natural, in my opinion) if you had just written that $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d'>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take all numbers equal to $\frac12$, except for $a'$, which is equal to $1$. Besides, take $M=\frac34$. Then$$\frac{a+b+c+d}{a'+b'+c'+d'}=\frac45.$$